# CSS: Safari (desktop), scroll in fixed div issue

Tags: css, angularjs, safari

Works well in Chrome, issue with safari (web)

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3220/

Expected behavior:

When you scroll down, the right column become fixed once its offset is at 0 (top the window). Then you scroll inside this div if your mouse is inside it.
The div is fixed by:

```
    .scroll-fixed{
        height: 300px;
        overflow-y:scroll;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
   }
```

The issue:
Sometimes it works as expected but sometime the right col doesn't scroll when become fixed, you can see the rest of the page continuing to moove up.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @Brandon Not yet..